# "Varying" noise function

Tags: javascript, perlin-noise

I am making a 2d sandbox game with procedural terrain generation, and for a few weeks, I have used [this](https://github.com/joeiddon/perlin) noise function by joeiddon, slightly modified so I can have multiple noise instances. The problem was that this function doesn't have a seed option, so there's no way to tell it to generate the same world two times. To solve that, I have been googling and coding for a few hours. Eventually, I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/josephg/noisejs) function (also slightly modified), which does support seeds. The problem is that when I use this function, there is almost no variation in the worlds. They can all be divided in five categories, and the difference between different worlds in the same category will never be more than a few blocks. So, basically, I either need a way to make the first function work with seeds, or I need to find out why the second function doesn't give enough variation. I don't know if this will help, but here is the code that initializes the noises based on a random seed:

```js
seed = Math.random();

grassNoise = new Perlin(seed);
goldMaxNoise = new Perlin(seed/7);
goldMinNoise = new Perlin(seed/2);
treeNoise = new Perlin(seed*3/2);
cloudUpNoise = new Perlin(seed);
cloudDownNoise = new Perlin(seed*1.2);
coalMaxNoise = new Perlin((seed - 78) / 3);
coalMinNoise = new Perlin(seed*7);
```

I only use the perlin2 function. Could anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using a different library that does support seeds and does what you want?

Comment: I have tried around 10 different functions, and most of them gave me really weird terrain generation, even when I modified them to give values between -1 and 1, like the two functions described in my question do, but other then these 2, none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Update: after exploring the worlds generated by the second function I found out that they were also very repetitive, and there was way less variation in height than I had with the first function. The best result would be achieved by somehow making the first function work with a seed, but looking at its code, it's probably impossible to make that work, since it just uses full randomness but saves the values. I think the p5.js library may be the solution, but I don't think you can create multiple noise instances with different seeds using that.